# Xamarin Component .xam file not getting created

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-component

I have been creating a Xamarin Component package by following [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_guide/).

The .yaml file already has created, but  the `.xam` file is not getting created.

My command console is showing:

```
No projects listed, and no_build not given, searching for solutions...
```

But I have followed all the steps mentioned by xamarin component submission guide. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error which you posted tells me that you either:

1. Don't have the [correct project structure for your component](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_guide/#Folder_Structure)
2. Have not included the source code for your component in the `src` folder
3. Have not updated your `Component.yaml` to [include the `build` element](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_guide/#Component.yaml)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I already figured that.I was not included build variable in my .yaml file.one more thing, do you know what is the thing "no build:true" in sample?

Comment: If you found a solution, then please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.